# Get 12V from normal PC UPS to supply low-power devises, such as Arduino

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics

I have an UPS, there is a battery 12V, is it ok to use directly out from the battery (12volts)? The reason because I have an extra one, and want to supply some small devices, for example an Arduino.

Comment: "OK" for what? Please clearly state what you're intending to do with the 12V.

Comment: One consideration is that in an UPS, there is no need to fully  isolate the 12V battery from the mains supply. But if you're using it externally, you probably need that isolation.

Comment: @FakeMoustache. Although there could be complications I do not see why the question of OP is not clear.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For example for supply an arduino or other small device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to, but ther are a number of caveats:

If you are drawing power when there is mains power available, the battery may not be able to charge at a reasonable rate, perhaps not at all.

Electrical isolation could be an issue, either in reality or for safety approvals.

The inverter part of the UPS will shut down when the battery is depleted to prevent damage to the battery. If you simply slap a load across the battery it could easily drain the battery to the point of damage if the power failure duration exceeds the hold-up time.